# cannot import all data in excel worksheet into sql in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel

I have excel file with 3 worksheet. I want to import it into database. I have successfully import only one worksheet into one table. This is my code:

```
string sqlConnectionString = @"Data Source=Magangpti1\SQLEXPRESS;Database=RcColdis;Trusted_Connection=true;Persist Security Info=True";

                string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=True";

                OleDbConnection con = null;
                DataTable dt = null;
                con = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
                con.Open();
                dt = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                con.Close();


                string sheetname = dt.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();
                con.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [" + sheetname + "]", con);

                OleDbDataReader dReader;
                dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString);
                sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Absolute_IDR";
                sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
                con.Close();


                string sheetname1 = dt.Rows[1]["Table_Name"].ToString();
                con.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [" + sheetname1 + "] ", con);

                OleDbDataReader dReader1;
                dReader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk1 = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString);
                sqlBulk1.DestinationTableName = "RC_Saham";
                sqlBulk1.WriteToServer(dReader1);
                con.Close();



                string sheetname2 = dt.Rows[2]["Table_Name"].ToString();
                con.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [" + sheetname2 + "]", con);
                OleDbDataReader dReader2;
                dReader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk2 = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString);
                sqlBulk2.DestinationTableName = "RC_Member";
                sqlBulk2.ColumnMappings.Add("Kode AK", "Kode AK");
                sqlBulk2.ColumnMappings.Add("Risk Charge", "Risk Charge"); 
                sqlBulk2.WriteToServer(dReader2);
                con.Close();

               return View("success");



  }

            else
            {
                return View("Index");
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

I cannot import the rest of worksheets into database. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

are you getting second sheet data into dReader, try giving hard coded  sheetname`

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [sheetname1]", con);`

Comment: No, I dont get second sheet data but I got third sheet data. I am confuse right now.  can you help me?

Comment: did you try hardcoding second sheet name?